# Query of searchkick get wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Query of searchkick get wrong result.
I have this one record in db:

```
2.2.0 :047 > Product.first
  #<Product id: 1, title: "Ball", description: "<p>Ball</p>\r\n", price: 10, material: "lalala", created_at: "2015-04-21 04:30:53", updated_at: "2015-04-21 04:30:53", preview: "images__1_.jpg", count: 20>
```

in controller `Product` and action `search` i have this code:

```
    def search
          @products = Product.search "*", where:
            {
              count: 10..18
            }
      end
```

and after this, a get result, that the with this values, count is exist.
But in db count = 20. And all time, get wrong result. I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get not correct result, 'cause i don't have hash, in model and need reindex of Model.

In model:

```
def search_data
    {
      count: count,
      price: price,
      title: title,
      category_id: categories.map($:id)
    }
end
```

and after that, in rails console wrote:

```
Product.reindex
```